# Void in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, void

I am learning Objective-C and I am wondering when people say that when you out void in a method it means that method returns nothing. What does that exactly mean? What would it "return" if it wasn't void? Please help.

Comment: You should read read an introductory book to programming or take a course. A quick Google search gave me this: http://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/programming-intro/0/1

Comment: Understand that "void" is used for (at least) two quite different things.  A "void pointer" (`void *`) is a pointer that is a pure address, with no associated data type.  When "void" is used as a return type from a method however, it means "nothing" -- no value is returned from the method, and attempting to return a value or use the (not) returned value will result in a compile error.

Comment: (But this is basic C/Java notation, and you should know it cold before you attempt to use Objective-C.  Objective-C is not a beginner's language, and you can learn a lot of wrong "facts" if you don't have the foundations down before you start into it.)

Answer (score 1):

void is exactly what you said, its just a word you use to let the compiler know that this function doesnt return anything, and you may omit the return statement in the function eg

```
- (void) myMethod {
    //do something here
}
```

where as if a method has a return type, then you would get a compile error if you didnt return something of that type

```
- (BOOL) myMethod {
    BOOL x = false;
    //do something
    return x;
}
```

so here we can see, in your words "What would it "return" if it wasn't void?" that it would return whatever you tell it to, the return type when you declare the method just needs to match what you are actually returning and thats all really.

note you can still return in a void function, but all it does is prematurely end the functions execution, eg

```
- (void) myMethod {

    BOOL x = false;

    if(x == false)
        return;

    x = true;
}
```

here we can see that the statement `x = true` will never execute, because it will go into the if statement and return, which will end the function (and not return anything)

Answer (score 0):

It would return whatever it has been declared/written to.